# Software Fragmentation on Android

Tags: android, ios

I am an iOS developer thinking of learning Android development. From what I've heard there are three main problems on android which you don't have on iOS:

Latest APIs not being available

Many different screen sizes

Software fragmentation(e.g bugs on some devices and not others).

The top two I have no problem with, but the last one does worry me a bit. How bad is fragmentation of this kind?

Comment: what do answer would you expect? it's 3 on a scale of 1-10... ?

Comment: If you talk about `iOS` you do have different screen sizes or form factors viz. `iPhone 3,3GS,4,4S`, `iPhone5`, `iPad`, `iPad-mini`. And dev needs to deal with all if developing universal app.

Answer (score 1):

Fragmentation is really only an issue if you're not paying attention to your min sdk level.

The Android docs have a nice little selector for level, set it to your min and it'll grey out any method not supported by that level and make sure your manifest has the min sdk value set.

There are probably some really specific set of issues that may arise from it, I recall an issue where saving an image from the camera on one device it was storing it in directory X by default and a different device was storing it in directory Y. But issues like that are few and far between.

You can take a look here http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html It gives a good overview of the percentage of devices running what OS and screen size.

Realistically you're probably not going to support anything less than Gingerbread 2.3.3, so it's highly probable you're going to be programming for API level 10 and nothing else. In fact you may not even notice any issues.

Answer (score 0):

How much this effects you will depend on the kind of app you're writing. If you're writing a fairly straightforward app with mainstream APIs that doesn't do anything particularly complicated you may never encounter any bugs in the Android APIs that bother you significantly.

On the other hand, if you're doing something more cutting edge, or using some of the less common APIs, you could find yourself having to deal with some horrible bugs. And when it happens, it's going to make you want to tear your hair out.

Not that iOS isn't without its problems, but as far as bugs go, you at least know that when they fix something you can start deprecating support for the previous versions of the OS after a fairly short period of time. You aren't left trying to support multiple hacks and workaround for years to come.

Personally I hated Android development because of these kinds of issues. But it will differ from person to person and project to project.